# how to get the clicked option in bootstrap selectpicker?

Tags: jquery, multiple-select, bootstrap-select

```
$('.excludeDaysPicker').selectpicker();
```

I have bootstrap selectpicker with 'multiple' choose option enabled.

```
<select class="excludeDaysPicker" multiple title="Not Selected">
<option value="Monday" id="1" class="excludeDays">Monday</option>
<option value="Tuesday" id="2" class="excludeDays">Tuesday</option>
<option value="Wednesday" id="3" class="excludeDays">Wednesday</option>
<option value="Thursday" id="4" class="excludeDays">Thursday</option>
<option value="Friday" id="5" class="excludeDays">Friday</option>
<option value="Saturday" id="6" class="excludeDays">Saturday</option>
<option value="Sunday" id="7" class="excludeDays">Sunday</option>
</select>
```

upon clicking the select option (either selecting or deselecting), I want to know which option is clicked.

I have tried.

```
$('.excludeDaysPicker').on('change',function(){
console.log("id::",$(this).children(':selected').attr('id'));
});
```

This actually does get me id. But since it is a multiple select enabled selectpicker. if already an option is selected. that option's id is get returned. for ex, in the screen shot below

[image]

if i click on wednesday, It gives me the id 2 (because tuesday is selected), But actually the id of wednesday is 3. I want the id of the option element i am clicking on.

And also I could not get the option element by giving the option element a  class , because the the bootstrap selectpicker plugin creates a list for all the option element like you can see below.

[image]

so,

```
 $('.excludeDays').click(function()
 {
  console.log("excluded day optionselected::",$(this).attr('id'));  
 });
```

doesn't help either.

is there way around guys?

Answer (score 6):

To get the respective id's of the options selected :

```
$('.excludeDaysPicker').on('change',function(){
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function()
    {
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
    });
});
```

UPDATE : To get the last selected value, push all selected values in the array and get the last element's id.

```
    var arr = new Array();
$('.selectpicker').on('change', function(){
     $(this).find("option").each(function()
     {
         if($(this).is(":selected"))
         {             
            id = $(this).attr("id");
            if(arr.indexOf(id) == -1)
            {
               arr.push(id);
            }
         }
         else
         {
             id = $(this).attr("id");
             arr = jQuery.grep(arr, function(value) {
              return value != id;
            });             
         }
     });

if(arr.length > 0)
    alert("Last selected id : " + arr[arr.length-1]);

  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wd1z0zmg/3/

Comment: hi dino. But I dont want all the options that are selected, but the one thats currently getting selected.

Comment: Please refer to the UPDATE section

Answer (score 1):

To get the last clicked value

```
$(".excludeDaysPicker").on("changed.bs.select", function(e, clicked, curr, prev) {
    var currentVal = $(this).find('option').eq(clicked).val();
    alert(currentVal);
});
```

if anyone looking for last clicked value of dynamically generated multiselect

```
$(document).on("changed.bs.select",".excludeDaysPicker", function(e, clicked, curr, prev) {
    var currentVal = $(this).find('option').eq(clicked).val();
    alert(currentVal);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/GannyBhai/cuygr0mf/22/